# What would the physical consequences be if space-time was embedded instead of metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

Suppose instead of using Riemann geometry, Einstein had postulated that 4D space-time was a 4D manifold embedded in a 6D space, and that gravity was a result of the shape of space-time in 6 dimensions. Instead of a metric $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ he might have used the 6D coordinates $X^N(x)$ with $N=1..6$ to describe the shape of the embedding and if you replace $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ in Einstein's equations with $\partial_\mu X^N(x)\partial_\nu X^N(x)$ you would get a field equation in $X$.

According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1204.pdf the Schwarzschield solution can be embedded in 6 dimensions. So the equations would predict the same orbit for Mercury and approximate to Newtonian gravity.

Are there any testable differences between the two theories?

As far as I can tell, the second theory would have less solutions that the first.

(When bringing in fermions they might differ because the obvious thing to do would be to define the vierbien as $e^N_\mu(x) = \partial_\mu X^N(x)$ which would be a 4x6 matrix instead of a 4x4 matrix.)

Comment: For the Riemannian case, the [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem) states that every manifold can be embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^n$, so both points of view are really the same. I believe there's a version of this theorem that has been proven for the Lorentzian case.

Comment: You can expect deviations from Newton's law at length scales of the order of the Kaluza Klein masses for the large extra dimensions, see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0511216 and references therein.

Comment: Yes you could embed GR into 10 dimensions. But if you embedded it into six only some solutions would remain. The schwarzschield being one of them and the most important. The large extra dimensions is a different matter I believe.